# How do loop methods like "if" & "while" capture the block before them?

Tags: ruby

In ruby you can do:

`do_stuff if foo == bar`

Technically speaking, is there a `&block` to capture the block of code before `if`? how does this stuff work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't methods, they are keywords. Their behavior is defined by the language specification and not restricted by the rules of the language. They can do anything they want.